# Fabric SDK for tweeter post

Tags: android, image, twitter, twitter-fabric

I use fabric sdk for Android.
Made all as in sample:

```
    TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
             .text(((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMSG)).getText().toString());

            if (imgFileName!=null && !imgFileName.equals("")) {
                builder.image(Uri.parse(imgFileName));
            }

            builder.show();
```

where is imgFileName is a link to image in internet (http://b2b4trade.com/images..../2.jpeg for example)
But when .show executed I see composer with my text but I don't see image. So my question is - how to compose tweet with image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that TweetComposer uses an Intent to share, the image URI you are setting as parameter must to be from a local image. So you would need to save the image to local disk before sharing it.

This question discuss a solution for that: [android share image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300959/android-share-image-from-url)

Also, check the section "Sharing Remote Images" of this tutorial: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents

Remember also that if the user doesn't have the Twitter app installed on device the TweetComposer will fallback to a Web Intent and in this case the image will not be available to be shared, independently of building the solution above.