# Gmail Can't attach empty file with url image android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I can't share Image with url :(I am using from Universal Image Library)

```
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("http://www.myurl.com/upload/Files/Walpaper/Logo/201631512317849.jpg");
    String text = "Look at my awesome picture";
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25135994/4898620

Comment: @Anup Dasari .Your response is true.Thanks a lot.Insert your response for up vote.

Comment: let's credit the rightful owner. Upvote his answer