# Share Image from url

Tags: android

I am tring to share an image which i fetch from Json. After a number of attempts i finally concluded with this code. It works well till i open whatsapp and select the contact i want to share, the image doesnt load from there and when i click on submit, it says sharing failed.

```
Drawable drawable1 = imageViewPreview.getDrawable();
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.image_preview);
File file = new File(SlideshowDialogFragment.this.getCacheDir(), String.valueOf(largeIcon + ".png"));

// FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
// largeIcon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);

file.setReadable(true, false);
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
intent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(intent);
```

if  i remove the comments

`FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);`
will show error message and i have to add try/catch then, the app crashes saying Nullpoint exception

Comment: please see this link for complete answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51186434/9060917

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = mBitmap;
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "photo.jpg");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {                       
        e.printStackTrace();
}
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/photo.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```